# How is array.filter checking for Array differences in my sample code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-difference

I am trying to understand how array.filter is returning array differences by checking if indexOf(x) is equal to -1? Why -1?

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) == -1; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf(x) return the index of your property. So 0 is the first property, -1 means there is no property found.

Answer (score 0):

`b.indexOf(x)` returns the index of parameter `x` in array `b`, *or* `-1` if `x` is not found in array `b`.

So, if `x` doesn't exist in *both* the `a` and `b` array, `indexOf()` returns `-1`, allowing `x` to appear in the result.

Comment: Thank you. This explanation makes most sense to me. I'm having a hard time really understanding the formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) == -1; });
}
```

For each item of array `a`, see if it exists in array `b`. If it does not (`indexOf()` returns `-1`), so return true, and keep it in the array. If it is in both arrays, return false.